# Creating custom IME for Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, nativescript

Is it possible to develop custom keyboard for Android and iOS with NativeScript? 
Does NativeScript support all the required things for that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. Have you read the [docs](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/input/accessibility-and-internationalization/keyboard-support) on keyboard support. No mention on allowing custom keyboard...

Comment: So what? NativeScript supports invokation of android and ios native api functions. It means that no special support of keyboard is needed.

Comment: In this [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html), you see that you must change info.pList file. With Swift or Obj-C, you could use UIKit Framework to customize the keyboard. Basically, you assign custom views to the inputView and inputAccessoryView properties. In other words, you can UIView object and assign it to your UITextField instance's inputView property - as in myTextField.inputView = [[UIView alloc] ...]; to override the keyboard. If you can do that with NativeScript, I think you'll get it.

Comment: I was asking about creating global custom keyboard for all apps.

Comment: You want to create a graphical component with a language that is not native (neither Java nor Obj-C or C++) ? Forget it.

Comment: There is no problem to create a graphical component with a language that is not native.

Comment: No doubt about it. Just thinking creating a universal keyboard for multiple mobile device from different providers is, IMO, a project in itself. Don't you agree ?

Comment: Of course, it is. I want to create a new keyboard app with NativeScript.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a plugin that exposes a custom numeric keyboard for iOS: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-numeric-keyboard

The same can be done for Android, but that's not where my need was when I created it.